# Remove string with known start and end string c#

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a HTML page string and I want to remove some string from the beginning of the HTML page. The code that I want to remove can be

`<!DOCTYPE HTML>`

or

`<!DOCTYPE anything in between>`

Regardless, it always start with `<!DOCTYPE` and ends with `>`. How do I search this line and remove it from the HTML page?

So far, I manage to search and remove the first string with `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` using the following code

```
PageString = e.Result.Replace("<!DOCTYPE HTML>", "").Trim();
```

But how about the second one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with the [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx) method:

```
PageString = Regex.Replace(e.Result, "<!DOCTYPE[^>]+>", string.Empty);
```

The pattern here will match any substring starting with `<!DOCTYPE` followed by one or more characters that are not `>`, followed by `>`. This will replace anything that looks like  `<!DOCTYPE anything in between>` including `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`.

You could be extra safe and actually improve the performance of this method if you use a start anchor (`^`) to only match this pattern at the beginning of the string:

```
PageString = Regex.Replace(e.Result, "^<!DOCTYPE[^>]+>", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I got an error `System.ArgumentException: parsing`

Comment: @PutraKg Sorry, I had the parameters in the wrong order. See my updated answer.